# Set object string ID's to Javascript parameters

Tags: javascript, html

I am starting coding with HTML, CSS and Javascript and I have a problem. I have a Blogger and my posts usually have a lot of content on it, so I was wondering to split my posts by "categorizing them" and use something like Spoiler. So, I am using some **div** tags just like above

```html
<div style="background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);">
    <p style="font-family:Segoe UI Light; color:white; vertical-align:middle; font-size:16px;">
        <img id="icon_1" src="show.png"
        style="width:20px; height:20px; margin:2px; vertical-align:middle;">Example</img>
    </p>
</div>
<div id="cont_1" style="display: none;">
  <p>just some stuff for an example<br/>
  content will be placed on this div</p>
  <p>I have set a default ID string, but don't know If I will need it at all</p>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have a **main div** which contains an picture (an icon related to show/hide) and a string input. Then, I have another div class, where the content will be placed. I have set and id, in this example **cont_1**. Plus, on load, this div will be collapsed/hidden so I set **display:none;**. You can also see that the **img tag** has an Id **icon_1**
Next, I built a JavaScript class. There, I will set the **cont_1** style display to **block;** and I also want to change the image **src**

This is my script code

```js
<script>
            function click1(item, ico)
            {
                var a = document.getElementById(item);
                if ( a.style.display == 'block' ) {
     a.style.display = 'none';
      icon_change(ico, "hide")
    }
                        
                    else {
      a.style.display = 'block';  
                  icon_change(ico, "show")
     }
                        
            }
   
   function icon_change(ico, visibility)
            {
                var image = document.getElementById(icon);
    var s = visibility;
                if ( s == "hide" ) {
    
                        image.src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAYAAAAeP4ixAAAA20lEQVRoQ+2YUQ7CIBBE2ZNZT66eDDExxmKajpMuMfj6S1k6b6cTIMokT0yioyDk1zqZ2pFa6+VdcEScswBkC6mdkLT10go/BLSOIORbC9IRhRjWUih172AtBRrWUihhLYMS1jKgkVoKNKylUCK1DEpYy4D2kVqN4rXVORm1Rk65tWPzsjp99qsjZGQ/SvmjjhwJltQyaLLXUqBhLYUSey2DEtYyoJFaCjSspVAitQxKWMuARmop0LCWQonUMig9LzJeM/ubD6Pk5pTUn/3ID92rhZA9QqPHp+nIHUEJrDNSwO0mAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";
                   } 
       
       else {
         image.src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAYAAAAeP4ixAAAAqklEQVRoQ+2UUQ6CMADF2Mn06Hqy4SfRv4YGMsv/K6xdGNsiz1jkHFsHuVvJilREMtDVksRibEWwOmlYEUksxlYEq5OGFZHEYmxFsDppWBFJLMZWBKuThj9F5pyvz7se0vvOwr7HGM8jrIOcpRZy/qgINHT5rN/v5Qm+PqAiFZEMdLUksRhbEaxOGlZEEouxFcHqpGFFJLEYWxGsThpWRBKLsRXB6qThMkV2e2UUM4Y5sY4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
       }
      
                
            }
   
</script>
```

Yeah.. my code is not very organized and probably I just need one function to complete the task, I have tried that and din't worked too..
My problem is carry the ID's to JavaScript function, that must be the issue on my code. I would like to have one or two javascript functions to work with multiple div, **the divs that contain the content** and will show and hide. 
I am using **OnClick** just like this

```html
<div Onclick="click1(content_1, icon_1)"/>
```

So, I tried to set **two parameters** to JavaScript, one it's the **div ID** and other the **image ID**
I am inserting it as String, should I do that? Do you know any easier way to do this? I would like to see if there are easier alternatives :)

Thanks! This is my post and hope it's clear enough..

Comment: in `function icon_change` you have `var image = document.getElementById(icon);` . That should be `ico` not `icon`

Comment: True, thanks for notice it :). But still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem you have there is that your parameters aren't called as string. It should be:

```
<div Onclick="click1('content_1', 'icon_1')"/>
```

You could simplify it this way:

```
function click1(which_div)
            {
                var a = document.getElementById("content_"+which_div);
                var image = document.getElementById("icon_"+which_div);

                if ( a.style.display == 'block' ) {
                    a.style.display = 'none';
                    image.src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAYAAAAeP4ixAAAA20lEQVRoQ+2YUQ7CIBBE2ZNZT66eDDExxmKajpMuMfj6S1k6b6cTIMokT0yioyDk1zqZ2pFa6+VdcEScswBkC6mdkLT10go/BLSOIORbC9IRhRjWUih172AtBRrWUihhLYMS1jKgkVoKNKylUCK1DEpYy4D2kVqN4rXVORm1Rk65tWPzsjp99qsjZGQ/SvmjjhwJltQyaLLXUqBhLYUSey2DEtYyoJFaCjSspVAitQxKWMuARmop0LCWQonUMig9LzJeM/ubD6Pk5pTUn/3ID92rhZA9QqPHp+nIHUEJrDNSwO0mAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";

                }

                    else {
                        a.style.display = 'block';      
                        image.src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAYAAAAeP4ixAAAAqklEQVRoQ+2UUQ6CMADF2Mn06Hqy4SfRv4YGMsv/K6xdGNsiz1jkHFsHuVvJilREMtDVksRibEWwOmlYEUksxlYEq5OGFZHEYmxFsDppWBFJLMZWBKuThj9F5pyvz7se0vvOwr7HGM8jrIOcpRZy/qgINHT5rN/v5Qm+PqAiFZEMdLUksRhbEaxOGlZEEouxFcHqpGFFJLEYWxGsThpWRBKLsRXB6qThMkV2e2UUM4Y5sY4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=";

                    }

            }
```

And you call it like this:

```
<div Onclick="click1('1')"/>
```

Comment: Works great :) Thanks a lot @JulienGrégoire . Just more one question. If I use **'content_1'** I am setting to Javascript parameter a string value which correspond to an ID string. If I just use **content_1** in the parameter how does the function interpret that?

Answer (score 0):

I have created following code snippet which gives same functionality/behavior as you expects but implemented little differently.

Hope this will solve your problem. You could test/play this on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kedar2a/2fvpt1zd/).

```
<figure onclick="showHide('show');" id="show">
    <img src="http://bioinformatica.upf.edu/2009/projectes09/Ex/resultats/seli/SelI_human_pfam_files/showButton.png" alt="An awesome picture">  
    <figcaption>Show</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure onclick="showHide('hide');" id="hide" style="display:none;">
    <img src="http://tweetingmeeting.com/images/hide-button.png">   
    <figcaption>Hide</figcaption>
</figure>


<div id="cont_1" style="display:none;">
    <p>just some stuff for an example<br/>
        content will be placed on this div</p>
    <p>some more content.....</p>
</div>


<script>
function showHide(activity)
{
    show = document.getElementById("show");
    hide = document.getElementById("hide");
    content = document.getElementById("cont_1");

    // a.style.display = "none";
    if(activity == "show")
    {
        show.style.display = "none";
        hide.style.display = "block";
        content.style.display = "block";
    }
    else if(activity == "hide")
    {
        show.style.display = "block";
        hide.style.display = "none";
        content.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```